# Get current year in package with setuptools?

Tags: python, package, setuptools

In my `setup.cfg` I have this:

```
[build-system]
requires =
    setuptools
    setuptools_scm
    wheel
```

Which allows me to have a `version.py`:

```
# coding: utf-8
# file generated by setuptools_scm
# don't change, don't track in version control
__version__ = version = '0.1.1.dev10+gcd2ad26'
__version_tuple__ = version_tuple = (0, 1, 1, 'dev10', 'gcd2ad26')
```

With which I do this in my `__init__.py`:

```
try:
    from . import version
    __version__ = version.version
    __version__ 
except ImportError:
    __version__ = None

__copyright__ = 'Copyright 2022 ACME INC'
```

I would like to auto complete the `Copyright` string with :

```
__copyright__ = f'Copyright {__YEAR__} {__COMPANY__}'
```

What is the best solution to tell setuptools to populate `__YEAR__` and `__COMPANY__`?

Comment: you can use datetime

Comment: @flow If I use DateTime, the year will not be hard coded. If someone uses an outdated package, it will still show the current year. The goal is to show the last year of the last commit.

Comment: sorry for the late response but do you have a GitHub repo for the project???